# Expect - Send command not prompt

Tags: tcl, expect, cisco

I'm trying to build a small expect script to reboot my **Cisco VCS devices**. However once logging into the device it doesn't have any prompting characters so I'm unsure how to initialise a send request

**Example Prompt:**

[image]

So far I tried

```
expect "OK/r"
send "command"

expect "OK/r/r"
send "command"
```

experimented with timeout but unsure how it works.

I also tried the autoexpect tool and it showed a weird character `[?1034h"` at the prompt which I tried including.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: The thing with `[?1034h"` is almost certainly some kind of ANSI escape sequence. They can get _very_ esoteric!

Answer (score 0):

I would think you should be able to expect the OK plus one or both of newline or carriage return. But you need backslashes for that, not forward ones. I would try "OK\r" or "OK\r\n".

Here's what you need to do: include `expect_internal 1` somewhere near the top of your script, then run it again. Expect will give you a ton of information on what it is and it is not matching. That should show you what it's receiving, and you will be able to craft your expect statement accordingly.

If you're unsure, edit your question to include the debugging output and I will try to help.

Comment: Thanks, my version of expect required exp_internal 1. The backslashes were just from my memory. Looks like my device was sending the command however exiting before getting feedback from the device. Thanks for your assistance.                               spawn ssh 10.0.20.11 -l admin -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no"   
expect "Password: "
send "password\r"
expect "OK\r
\r
"
send "xcommand Boot\r"
expect "OK"

Comment: `exp_internal 1` is the correct syntax, always. That was my bad... not sure what I was thinking when writing my answer! I'm glad it helped you detect what was going on. If you find the response useful don't forget to mark or upvote the answer!  :-)